# Defining named module and requiring it at the same time

Tags: requirejs

In my application I want programmatically create named module and when access it using define. In simplified form it looks following:

```
define("myModule", [], function() {
    return {
        myModule: true
    };
});
var obj = require('myModule');
```

While I don't see any issues why it would not work this way require.js certainly does and says:

```
MODULE NAME ... HAS NOT BEEN LOADED YET FOR CONTEXT: ...
```

It works if I change my code following way:

```
define("myModule", [], function() {
    return {
        myModule: true
    };
});
require(['myModule'], function(obj){

});
```

But now it is async code and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of `require` which *looks* synchronous is really just [sugar](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) to allow writing code in a style more like that of CommonJS and help with porting CommonJS code to RequireJS. Unfortunately, the error message it generates is not properly indicating the nature of the problem. This form of `require` works fine, and will return a module, as long as the module has *already* been defined and *initialized*. If it has not been defined and initialized already, then it fails. Since this form of `require` does not initialize modules, you have to use the asynchronous form to initialize them.

I don't think this is about to change. As of July last year James Burke (the lead developer for RequireJS) has stated that there are [no plans](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/requirejs/synchronous|sort%3adate/requirejs/82bFAdfkHAo/1NLSeA_VFxoJ) for supporting synchronous dynamic loading of scripts.

I can see two ways around this:

1. Wrap the whole application in one async `require` call that loads all modules for which you want to use `var foo = require('foo');`. I know you mentioned wanting to avoid async calls but you did not specify whether what you wanted to avoid is having async `require` calls *spread* throughout your app. What I'm suggesting here is to have *one* async `require` call like this that starts your application:

   ```
   require(['main', 'myModule', ... other modules ...], function (main) {
       main();
   });
   ```

   Supposing that the `main` module is the main entry point to your application, then anywhere in the code of your application you could do `var myModule = require('myModule');` because `myModule` is guaranteed to have been defined and initialized *before* the sync-looking `require` executes.
2. Create a parallel system to RequireJS. Something like this works:

   ```
     var syncmap = Object.create(null);
     function syncdefine(name, factory) {
         var mod = factory();
         syncmap[name] = mod;
         define(name, mod);
     }

     function syncrequire(name) {
         return syncmap[name];
     }

     syncdefine("myModule", function () {
         return {
             myModule: true
         };
     });

     console.log("outside", syncrequire("myModule").myModule);

     require(["myModule"], function (mm) {
        console.log("inside", mm.myModule);
     });
   ```

   The `syncdefine` function defines a module for RequireJS and for immediate use with `syncrequire`. Calling `syncrequire` returns the module right away. It can also be required through RequireJS' `require` call.

   This code is meant for illustration purposes only. It is not anywhere close to being a general solution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and providing possible solutions. First option is nice. Once again - thank you very much.